# c# WPF WebBrowser set value of Text Box

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

i wonder how to set value of textbox using webbrowser. For example i want to open google search page and autocomplete search textbox to specific value. I found that in win forms i can do it using GetElementById and SetAttribute methods. Unfortunately i can't use this methods in wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebBrowser control in WPF doesn't currently support this. However, you can use the ['WindowsFormsHost'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) control to use the WinForms WebBrowser in your WPF application.

Like this:

```
<Window 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
    <Grid>
      <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:WebBrowser />
      </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```